# extract text from div selector with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get the price texts in 
[potterybarn](https://www.potterybarnkids.com/shop/easter/easter-shop-all-baskets/) in scrapy shell. I used `scrapy shell "https://www.potterybarnkids.com/shop/easter/easter-shop-all-baskets/"` then trying to get the price inside span `class="price-state price-sale"` is there a way to extract entire text inside span with going into each span inside it?

I tried

`response.xpath('//span[@class="price-state price-sale"]/text()').extract()` also `response.xpath('//span[@class="price-state price-sale"]//text()')[0].extract()`

I need a way to extract all texts inside the selector weather it has inner spans,divs,...

I checked [How can i extract only text in scrapy selector in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489473/how-can-i-extract-only-text-in-scrapy-selector-in-python), also [Scrapy extracting text from div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164587/scrapy-extracting-text-from-div) in this one the answer assumes that it will contain only span children which will work in that example and this one. but is there a more general way to correctly extract all text inside children because `//text()` isn't working.

Comment: I took a quick glance at the HTML. It appears that the span elements of class "price-amount" are the ones with the price as inner text. The span elements of class "price-state price-sale" have '\n' as their inner text.

Comment: @DMfll the span contains the text "Sale $5.99 – $18.99"  in html format (including \n ...)

Comment: Yes. I see. I'm using lxml to look at the elements. You will find that if you iterate over all the descendants as opposed to children of the element at `'/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span/span[2]'` you will get an array of `['\nSale\n', '\n', '$', '5.99', '\n', '$', '18.99']` as text items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are more efficient ways, but the following `xpath` does the job. The `string()` on xpath gather text from all children nodes.

You can find more information about differences between `string()` and `text()` on this post [Difference between text() and string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string)

```
prices = [
    r.xpath('string(.)').extract_first() 
    for r in response.xpath('//span[@class="price-state price-sale"]')
]
```

As you can see on results, one product per row. It could be cleaned with `replace` for example, or prices extracted using `regex`

```
>>> prices
['\n\nSale\n\n\n$5.99\n–\n\n$18.99\n', '\n\nSale\n\n\n$6...
```

Other option would be to do it in two steps, using `text()` instead of `string()` and cleaning data before `join` operation:

```
>>> prices = []
>>> for r in response.xpath('//span[@class="price-state price-sale"]'):
>>>     price = [p.strip() for p in r.xpath('.//text()').extract() if p.strip()]
>>>     prices.append(' '.join(price))
```

Results in this case are already cleaned

```
>>> prices
['Sale $ 5.99 – $ 18.99', 'Sale $ 6.99 – $ 18.99', 'Sale $ 6.99...
```